# I can't add a distribution Provisioning Profile that is active

Tags: ios, xcode, software-distribution

[image: Distribution Profile pending in iOS Provisioning Profiles]

Has anyone else experienced this lately? 
I can't add a distribution Provisioning Profile that is active.
It stays refreshing for a long time about 1-hour. I finally refreshed and it was in a status of pending. I tried to create another one and that one went to pending as well.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just had to wait a longer amount of time and it became active...patience Daniel-son!

Comment: What else can I say? I had to wait for a longer amount of time and it finally was active. You know I was going to delete this post, but I could see how it could be useful to someone. The answer was to wait longer.